# Why does x86 assembly print garbage?

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, tasm

I'm trying to output a message using tasm, 1st using .com program (printed out garbage values besides the message) and then .exe program which worked just fine. Here is the code:

```
code segment para public 'code'
    assume cs:code, ds:code
    org 100h
start:
    jmp entry
    message db "Hello World! $"
    entry:
        mov ah,09h
        lea dx, message
        int 21h

        mov ah,4ch
        mov al,00
        int 21h
code ends
end start
```

What's wrong with my code ?

Comment: Works fine here, using `dosbox`.

Comment: `Int 21/AH=09h` expects the string to be located in `DS:DX`. You're not setting `DS`.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar `COM` starts up with `DS` already initialized.

Comment: @Jester I'm using dosbox too, but I get garbage :/

Comment: How do you compile and link?

Comment: tasm name; tlink name; name

Comment: That creates an exe file. To get a com file you need to use `tlink /t`. Also you should run it explicitly with extension to make sure you really run the one you want (in case both exe and com happen to exist).

Comment: Yeah you're right. So *silly question* when I write a .com program I should save it with the `.com` extension and not `.asm` extension?

Comment: No, you need to save it with `.asm`. That's the source code. The resulting program will be `name.com`. That is done automatically by `tlink /t`, you just need to pass that `/t` and then run the appropriate binary.